# Filtering based on calculation inside whereHas Eloquent Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to filter jobs which have location distance less than certain limit as follows. `Job` and `Location` have many-many relation.

Job.php

```
class Job extends Model {
    protected $table = 'jobs';
    protected $fillable = ['company_id', 'role_id', 'job_title'];

    public function location() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Pincode', 'job_pincodes', 'job_id', 'location_id');
    }
}
```

Pincode.php

```
class Pincode extends Model {
    protected $table = 'pincodes';
    protected $fillabe = ['location', 'pincode', 'state', 'district','lati','longi'];

    public function jobs() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Job');
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to access each row of relationship inside `whereHas`. Please help.

```
 $user_lat = 28.7041;
 $user_long = 77.1025;
 $distance = 12;
 $result = Job::whereHas('location',function($query)
 use($user_lat,$user_long,$distance) {
     // I don't know how to access $location 
     $query->whereRaw('3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians(?) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) * sin(radians(?)) ) <=?', array($location->lati, $user_lat, $location->longi, $user_long, $location->lati,$user_lat, $distance));
 })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `with()` and then access the location through `query`

```
$result = Job::with('location').whereHas('location',function(query)
use($user_lat,$user_long,$distance) {
     // I don't know how to access $location 
     $query->whereRaw('3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians(?) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) * sin(radians(?)) ) <=?', array($query->location->lati, $user_lat, $query->location->longi, $user_long, $query->location->lati,$user_lat, $distance));
 })->get();
```